# UI Grid: Failed to decode downloaded font OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

Tags: angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I know so many issues were reported for font, but after looking through all of them still i am not able to find solution for this issue. I am creating an mvc .NET application. have moved all the font files in font folder and changed my css to. Since I am facing this issue on visual studio, i am unable to provide an working example.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ui-grid';
  src: url('../fonts/ui-grid.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/ui-grid.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/ui-grid.woff') format('woff'),           url('../fonts/ui-grid.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/ui-grid.svg?#ui-grid') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

screenshot for issue in Chrome:
[image]

screenshot for issue in Firefox:
[image]

screenshot for issue in internet explorer:
[image]

**UI Grid version : 4.0.2**

Answer (score 1):

You need to download your required .woff file and .ttf file from ui-grid resources to the dir where your ui-grid.css is

https://github.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/blob/master/ui-grid.ttf

https://github.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/blob/master/ui-grid.woff

Or in your .html file, you directly point to the official ui-grid site so you don't need to reference files. They will take care themselves

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css"/>
```

So 2 things you should do if the above is not your option

## 1. verify paths url('../fonts/ui-grid.woff'), url('../fonts/ui-grid.ttf')

## 2.  You need to verify whether your MIME type is correct returned by your format ()'s and supported by your internet server.  Have you added these

## 1. MIME 'woff' is APPLICATION/X-WOFF and

## 2. MIME for 'ttf's is APPLICATION/octet-Stream

to your server? It's got to be these 2 possibilities, either your path is not correct or your server config MIME is not equipped.

The original ui-grid.css has

```
src: url('ui-grid.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('ui-grid.woff') format('woff'), url('ui-grid.ttf') format('truetype'), url('ui-grid.svg?#ui-grid') format('svg');
```

but yours are

```
url('../fonts/ui-grid.woff'), url('../fonts/ui-grid.ttf')
```

so, do you really have ui-grid.woff on your fonts path?

Comment: They are already present in fonts folder and for same I have also changed path too, which is given in question

Comment: I have edited my answer to re-answer your question!  Please check.